# WPF - Generate BitmapSource from Over state of a button

Tags: wpf, button, mouseevent, bitmapsource

I can generate a `BitmapSource` from a button fine, however it always is just the image of the normal state of the button.

I want to be able to generate a `BitmapSource` of the over state of a button.

I tried calling
`VisualStateManager.GoToState((FrameworkElement)target, "MouseOver", true);` before calling my code to generate the BitmapSource.  It correctly changes the button to the overstate on the GUI, but the `BitmapSource` is still that of the button in the normal state.

Comment: Have you tried using triggers? http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates—Data_Triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. `VisualStateManager.GoToState((FrameworkElement)target, "MouseOver", true);` just begins the transition to the specified state. I needed to give control back to the UI thread and wait for the state to actually change before trying to save the bitmap.